# Can I name both rows and columns of a matrix in Octave?

Tags: dataframe, matrix, octave

Is it possible to rename the indices of a matrix in octave?
I need specific names for the rows and columns. Can I do that; if yes, how?
I have to assemble matrices to get one large matrix. And it is not normal concatenation. There is a specific element-to-element transformation which requires particular naming of the rows and columns. 
How can I achieve this?
Also, can I access these elements later on using these names?

Answer (score 5):

Use the octave [dataframe package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/dataframe/index.html) which is based on R's `data.frame` data type. This package first version was 0.8, and released in October 2010. At that time, Octave latest release was 3.2.4.

```
octave> pkg load dataframe
octave> x = dataframe (rand (7, 3), "colnames", {"foo", "bar", "baz"})
x = dataframe with 7 rows and 3 columns
_1      foo     bar     baz            
Nr   double  double  double            
 1 0.227254 0.17613 0.11311            
 2 0.626745 0.47250 0.74212            
 3 0.062161 0.49492 0.40909            
 4 0.636538 0.25582 0.92339            
 5 0.906660 0.70828 0.63547            
 6 0.521425 0.95103 0.81526            
 7 0.305666 0.28913 0.28903
octave> x.foo
ans =

   0.227254
   0.626745
   0.062161
   0.636538
   0.906660
   0.521425
   0.305666
```

Comment: In the case where the number of columns and rows is very large, do I have another way of doing this? I will not be able to manually name each and every row and column in such a case. Can I run a loop or use names from an array or something?

Comment: @swatipratyusha the names of columns are in a cell array. Your question makes little sense as it is. You should make a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: Let the question just be what one should do when the number of rows and columns to be named is very large.